# .Net MVC Threading Long running process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have a long running process in my MVC application(C#).
Its building data for many reports.

Some of the clients could take several minutes or longer to calculate. Is running the process in a separate thread the best option?
Is there another way to allow the process to run, while allowing the user to still use the rest of the site?

If threading is the best solution, any good sites or stackoverflow threads to look at on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I've had cases like those, I usually would build a service to asynchronously process requests, and return a handle that I could use to check on its status in a database.  IMHO, splitting it off as a thread in the web application seems like you'd be trying to shove a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: I do have a statustracker already being used, and can reuse. Not being used for something that runs terribly long like these report calcs.

Comment: I'm wondering about the service you use. Is this just a service running outside of the app and/or IIs? Or is it a webservice? Are you using a command pattern(like hatchet below). This is where is get a little lost in coding, getting something to run on its own, not have to wait for the controller/action to post back.

Comment: Currently looking the AsyncController. A lot of other sites keep pointing to this for long running services. Using it for the status tracker already. Trying to figure out how to use it for a long running service.

Comment: Looks like a windows service is the way to go. Cause i want allow the user to leave the page, and AsyncController will return a Completed View when done. This would work great if i wanted to have a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

I've used two methods to solve this. If the work is guaranteed to not be TOO long running, I've kicked off a thread to do the work and return immediately to the user. When we couldn't make that guarantee, we used a queue (we happened to use MSMQ) for executing long running tasks. This processing was done on a different server apart from IIS. A benefit of this is that we built in a wait and retry on failure mechanism. So besides it handling long running tasks, we also used it for anything that might fail in a way that was inconvenient to handle in our MVC app. The main example of this is sending an email. Rather than do that in the MVC app we would just toss an email task on the queue. We used the Command Pattern for the task objects placed on the queue. Once we had that mechanism in place, we stopped using the technique of spawning a thread from our MVC code.

Comment: Your thread could be torn down in the middle of execution if the app domain recycles (e.g. if web.config is updated, or by default this happens every 29 hours in IIS).  Only use this approach if you can tolerate your thread stopping abruptly.

Comment: @EricJ. - if by "this method" you mean running another thread in IIS, I agree. That's why we use the MSMQ method I described. The Windows service that processes the queue and does the work is written to not only do fail/retry, but to gracefully handle a server shutdown so nothing slips between the cracks.